# Overlay on website goes in front of all elements

Tags: html, css, overlay, z-index

I made a photo gallery (html + javaScript + CSS). It works very simple: by clicking on each thumbnail a lightbox appears with a preview and a caption. When it happens the rest of the page, except for the lightbox itself, is covered with low opacity overlay. It worked fine but right now when I open any lightbox the overlay goes over (in front of) the entire page and the lightbox appears also behind it. Everything is covered with semi-transparent black. I suspect it's the problem with z-index, yet I didn't change a single z-index value within the code at all. What else can it be? Where did I make a mistake?

The CSS for the lightbox and the overlay looks like so:

```
.lightbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  z-index: 10;
}

.lightbox.preload {
  transition: none !important;
}

.lightbox.open {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.lightbox .close {
  background-color: #52616b;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #1e2022;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.4em;
  right: -0.4em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* overlay */

.lightbox .close::before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  content: "";
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

There is more code but the rest of it is just for styling of image, text and link elements and they are all displayed correctly. So the problem must be within the lines I quoted. I'll be grateful for help.

Comment: I think you meant to put the overlay on the `.lightbox` and not the `.close` element - e.g. `.lightbox::before`.

Comment: I checked and you are correct. Strange, as on the backup page I had saved it was working with .close. Anyway, thank you very much. It saved a lot of my time and nerves!